# WP7 Periodic Agent - share namespace with main application?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, namespaces, scheduler

I have some code in my main app that calls a web service and gets some information to put in a live tile. 
I want the tile to be self-updating via a periodic agent however I don't want to duplicate code and I need to access the settings for authentication...

Can I just change the namespace of my Scheduler Agent to be the same as my main application so I can access the existing code/configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A periodic agent requirement is that your main project references the periodic agent's project. If you forget this step, then your agent won't work.

Because of this requirement, you can't reference the main project from the agent, otherwise you would have cyclic references. So just put your common code in the agent's project, and use it from the main project as needed. If you want to make things cleaner, you can even make a third project which will be referenced by both the main project and the agent's project.

Comment: Thanks, How should I go about handing user data to the agent? The agent would need to know information such as username, password and API key. Could I have the agent storing these details and then access them from the main application?

Comment: Sure. If you store them in the isolated storage, then both the agent and the main app will be able to access it.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm really new to all this C#/WP7 stuff. I don't understand how I actually access the code in the agent's project from the main project. Can you provide a link to an example?

Comment: I think it's the "adding a reference" part you're missing. In Visual Studio, right click on your main project, select "Add reference", go in the "Projects" tab, and your agent's project. Now you can use from the main project the classes that are stored in the agent's project, as long as they are declared as public.

Comment: Ah of course! I can't put this to the test just now, but this seems very promising.

Comment: This works, thanks!
Though in terms of the MS app review process, would there be any issues with this?

Comment: Not at all. There's no restriction on adding a reference to another Windows Phone project.